# Пример с вычислением широты и долготы

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Подскажите пример реализации карты с меткой, при перемещении которой вычисляются координаты широты и долготы метки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            placemark.geometry.events.add('change', function () {
                var coords = placemark.geometry.getCoordinates();
                ...
            });
```